# Mysql Select statement to and convert timestamp on the fly

Tags: mysql, sql, str-to-date

I have a MYSQL table which has a column name called timestamp stored in string format. the timestamps in this column are in the following format e.g. '20/10/2014 05:39 PM'

Now how can select a row and convert the timestamp column to 24HR format on the fly.

basically I want something like this.
`SELECT id, user,  STR_TO_DATE(timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p') as timestamp FROM mytable WHERE user="bob"`;

but this does not work. looks like its not recognizing the timestamp variable inside `STR_TO_DATE` sql function and its retuning NULL for the timestamp column.

Please help.

Comment: *"I have a MYSQL table which has a column name called timestamp stored in string format."* - This is where you went wrong. The right way would be to store it as a date or timestamp, and convert it when you want to format it in a specific format. I think the query goes wrong, because `timestamp` is a reserved word. Try to enclose it in backticks (`STR_TO_DATE(\`timestamp\`, '%....')`), or rename the column altogether.

Comment: tried both enclosing and  then renaming the column name. still returning NULL as value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks fine to me:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20/10/2014 05:39 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p');
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('20/10/2014 05:39 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p') |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-10-20 17:39:00                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

(I know this should be a Comment, but is an Answer in order to get formatting.)

Comment: It also works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2ca6/3  Perhaps the original data has null in the column?

Comment: yes, this works if you supply the data directly. but i want to select a column and convert that column results on the fly. i.e. `timestamp` column.

Comment: My bad. i had some typo in my query and it works. thanks for your time. it works now.

Answer (score 0):

use date_format function instead of str_to_date:

`SELECT id, user,  date_format(timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i %p') as timestamp FROM mytable WHERE user="bob";`